# Draw curve between draggable points with control points to adjust curve SVG and d3.js

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, svg

I want to show several curved lines based on JSON data i retrieve from the database which are x,y coordinates, each line is a separate array of several objects containing coordinates to make the full path.

All of points must be draggable and between every 2 points must be a control point to adjust the curve of each line.

So far with the help of the internet i have a set of points that are draggable but the control points for the curve are just one of the coordinates and not created dynamically, maybe the control point position will have to be worked out and fed into the array before the output but i am not sure if that is the way to do it. 
(Hope that makes sense)

See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mattstudios/v0z5wanp/)

```
var point_positions = [];
var json_data_muliple_lines = [[{"id": "82","x": "100","y": "50"}, {"id": "83","x": "25","y": "110"}, {"id": "97","x": "90","y": "150"}, {"id": "98","x": "150","y": "224"}, {"id": "99","x": "250","y": "150"}, {"id": "100","x": "300","y": "200"}, {"id": "100","x": "320","y": "230"}],[{"id": "1","x": "120","y": "60"}, {"id": "2","x": "30","y": "150"}, {"id": "3","x": "120","y": "170"}, {"id": "4","x": "180","y": "260"}, {"id": "5","x": "300","y": "250"}]];
var json_data = [{"line_pi_id": "82","x": "100","y": "50"}, {"line_pi_id": "83","x": "25","y": "110"}, {"line_pi_id": "97","x": "90","y": "150"}, {"line_pi_id": "98","x": "150","y": "224"}, {"line_pi_id": "99","x": "250","y": "150"}, {"line_pi_id": "100","x": "300","y": "200"}, {"line_pi_id": "100","x": "320","y": "230"}];

$.each(json_data, function(i, item) {
    line_response = json_data[i];
    var line_pi_id = line_response.line_pi_id;
    var li_x = parseInt(line_response.x);
    var li_y = parseInt(line_response.y);

    point_positions.push({
        x: li_x,
        y: li_y
    })
})
var svg = d3.select('#curves').append('svg')
    .attr({
        width: 1000,
        height: 1000
    });
var handleRadius = 8;

function curves_init(point_positions) {
    var curves = [{
        type: 'Q',
        points: point_positions
    }];
    console.log("curves", curves);
    var controlLineLayer = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'control-line-layer');
    var mainLayer = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'main-layer');
    var handleTextLayer = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'handle-text-layer');
    var handleLayer = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'handle-layer');

    var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
        .origin(function(d) {
            return d;
        })
        .on('drag', dragmove);

    function dragmove(d) {
        d.x = d3.event.x;
        d.y = d3.event.y;
        d3.select(this).attr({
            cx: d.x,
            cy: d.y
        });
        d.pathElem.attr('d', pathData);
        if (d.controlLineElem) {
            d.controlLineElem.attr('d', controlLinePath);
        }
        handleTextLayer.selectAll('text.handle-text.path' + d.pathID + '.p' + (d.handleID + 1))
            .attr({
                x: d.x,
                y: d.y
            }).text(handleText(d, d.handleID));
    }
    show_curves(controlLineLayer, mainLayer, handleTextLayer, handleLayer, curves, drag);
}

function pathData(d) {
    var p = d.points;
    curve = [
        'M', p[0].x, ' ', p[0].y,
        'Q', p[1].x, ' ', p[1].y,
        ' ', p[2].x, ' ', p[2].y,
        ' ', p[3].x, ' ', p[3].y,
        ' ', p[4].x, ' ', p[4].y,
        ' ', p[5].x, ' ', p[5].y,
        ' ', p[6].x, ' ', p[6].y
    ].join('');

    console.log("curve", curve);
    return curve;
}

function controlLinePath(d) {
    var values = [];
    d.points.forEach(function(p) {
        values.push(p.x);
        values.push(p.y);
    });
    return 'M' + values.join(' ');
}

function handleText(d, i) {
    return 'p' + (i + 1) + ': ' + d.x + '/' + d.y;
}

function show_curves(controlLineLayer, mainLayer, handleTextLayer, handleLayer, curves, drag) {
    mainLayer.selectAll('path.curves').data(curves)
        .enter().append('path')
        .attr({
            'class': function(d, i) {
                return 'curves path' + i;
            },
            d: pathData
        })
        .each(function(d, i) {
            var pathElem = d3.select(this),
                controlLineElem,
                handleTextElem;
            if (d.type !== 'L') {
                controlLineElem = controlLineLayer.selectAll('path.control-line.path' + i)
                    .data([d]).enter().append('path')
                    .attr({
                        'class': 'control-line path' + i,
                        d: controlLinePath(d)
                    });
            }
            handleTextElem = handleTextLayer.selectAll('text.handle-text.path' + i)
                .data(d.points).enter().append('text')
                .attr({
                    'class': function(handleD, handleI) {
                        return 'handle-text path' + i + ' p' + (handleI + 1);
                    },
                    x: function(d) {
                        return d.x
                    },
                    y: function(d) {
                        return d.y
                    },
                    dx: 10,
                    dy: 0
                })
                .text(handleText);
            handleLayer.selectAll('circle.handle.path' + i)
                .data(d.points).enter().append('circle')
                .attr({
                    'class': 'handle path' + i,
                    cx: function(d) {
                        return d.x
                    },
                    cy: function(d) {
                        return d.y
                    },
                    r: handleRadius
                })
                .each(function(d, handleI) {
                    d.pathID = i;
                    d.handleID = handleI;
                    d.pathElem = pathElem;
                    d.controlLineElem = controlLineElem;
                })
                .call(drag);
        });
}
curves_init(point_positions);
```

So i need your help to figure out how to create a control point between every 2 coordinates and if i need to change the JSON output to plot the control point coordinate and how to adapt this code for multiple paths as it only works if the pathData() function is set manually to match the JSON output.

Any help is appreciated! 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To convert a straight line to an equivalent bezier curve, just insert your control points at the 1/3 and 2/3 position between the start point and end point.

```html
<svg width="500" height="500">
  
  <path d="M 100 100
           C 200 200 300 300 400 400"
        fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width="10"/>
  
</svg>
```